# debug android : connect to sqlite db on phone

Tags: android

I'm building an application with a SQLite db in it. Some data is not erased as it should be, I'd like to run ad hoc queries in the existing db to debug.

Is there a way to connect to the SQLite db on the phone (or the emulator) while in debug mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to your device (or the emulator) using [this manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite). 
Use adb to connect to the emulator:

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

and then launch the sqlite3 application with the database you need:

```
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db
```

Then you can run any SQL query you want.

Comment: I don't think you can use sqlite3 on an actual device

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sqlite3` command to open the database. If you have a rooted device (works on the emulator too), use `su` to become root and get access to private files. If not, just make your app debuggable and use `run-as` to open the DB. Something like:

```
run-as my.package sqlite3 /data/data/my.package/databases/my.db
```